# Is it possible to prove reflexive, symmetric and transitive properties of equality and the transitive property of inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, axioms

This may be a bit of a trivial question, but can one prove the reflexive, symmetric and transitive properties of equality and the transitive property of inequality of real numbers?(and if so, how? Is there a fairly straightforward, possibly algebraic method?) i.e. Is it possible to prove that $\forall\;a, b\in\mathbb{R}$
$$a=a,$$ $$\text{if } a=b \text{ then } b=a,$$  and $$\text{if } a=b \text{ and } b=c \text{ then } a=c.$$  Also, $$\text{if } a<b \text{ and } b<c \text{ then } a<b$$
The sources that I've read so far seem to have conflicting points of view.

Comment: I mean, from the sets point of view, the equality relation is just $R=\Delta \Bbb R = \{(x,x): x\in\Bbb R\}$, and so you can check the properties easily.

Comment: Could one use the following *axiom of order*: Let $a>0$ and $b>0$ then $a+b>0$, and the definition that $a>b\iff a-b>0$. Also, $a<b\iff b>a$. Using this,  let $a<b$ and $b<c$, it follows then,  that $b-a>0$ and $c-b>0$. This implies that $(b-a) +(c-b) >0\Rightarrow c-a>0\Rightarrow c>a\iff a<c$.  Therefore, if $a<b$ and $b<c$ then $a<c$.  Would this be correct? If so,  can a similar argument be used to prove that equality is transitive (i.e. By starting with $a=b$ and $b=c$ and then using that if $a=0$ and $b=0$ then $a+b=0$, and also,  if $a=b$ then $a+(-b) =0$)?

Comment: The transitive property of strict ordering: "if $a<b$ and $b<c$ then $a < \color{red}{c}$".

Comment: @Will Yes, that's also not really a problem, it really all depends on what set of axioms or other definitions you're using. For equality, I would never try and prove it directly since all relations are fundamentally sets and the fact I mentioned earlier is so much easier, but for the inequalities, that's not a bad choice.

Comment: Thanks for your help Adam. Out of interest, do you have any notes/links to notes that discuss the equality relation from the sets point of view (I find the notation a bit confusing as to what it intuitively means and can't seem to find anything on it)? Does the equality relation follow from the idea of ordered pairs that $(x,y)=(y,x)\iff x=y$?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. The equality relation on the real line is stated formally as follows:

$$S\subseteq R^2 = \{(x,x)|x\in R\}$$

Naturally,we assume $S\neq \emptyset$.So let's check all the axioms for an equivalence relation.

(1) Reflexivity. Clearly for every $x \in R$ , $(x,x)\in S$.

(2) Symmetry: Let a = b where $a,b\in R$. Then $(a,b)\in S$. 2 ordered pairs in a relation S are the same iff for $(a,b) ,(c,d) \in S$,then a=c and b=d i.e. (a,b) = {{a},{a,b}} = {{c},{c,d}}=(c,d). So since a=b, {{a},{a,b}} = {{b},{b,a}}. But this means $(b,a) \in S$ and b=a.

(3) Transitivity: Let a=b and b=c where $a,b,c\in R$. That means $(a,b), (b,c) \in S$. By reflexivity, b=b. Since a=b, (b,c) = (a,c). So $(a,c) \in S$. Since $(b,c)\in S$, $(c,b)\in S$ by symmetry. Since a=b, $(c,a)\in S$. But now, since $(a,c) and (c,a)\in S$, then a=c and that does it. So equality on **R** is an equivalence relation.

For inequality, a stricter ordering relation then "=" is needed. You have the right idea with your proof,but you have to be a little more careful about the axioms and make sure the order relation is defined via ordered pairs as we've done above. You've got the right idea,though. See if you can finish it yourself.

Comment: What the heck did I do wrong in my Jax code for S? Someone let me know please?!?

Comment: Having thought about it a little, can one define the inequality relation as $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}=\lbrace (x,y)\vert y=x+a,\; a\in\mathbb{R}^{+}\rbrace$? From this we have that $x<y\iff y=x+a$ and $y<z\iff z=y+b$, it follows that $z=y+b=(x+a)+b=x+(a+b)=x+c$ where $c=a+b\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$, and so as $z=x+c$ it follows that $x<z$. Would this be correct?

Comment: Thanks by the way Mathemagician! A couple of other questions though, where does the set definition of equality come from? (I can't find any notes on it, any links would be much appreciated). Also, is the idea of defining equality as the relation $S=\lbrace(x,x)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\vert\;x\in\mathbb{R}\rbrace$ that the set is the collection of ordered pairs constructed from a real number and itself, and then it follows from equality of ordered pairs that $(x,x)=(x,y)\iff x=y$  and therefore $(x,y)\in S\iff x=y$ ?!

Comment: @Will The modern definition of set equality is usually attributed to K.Kuratowski,although there were equivalent definitions advocated by Zermelo,Hausdorff and others. There are some very nice,brief notes by our own Pete Clark here: http://math.uga.edu/~pete/3200relationsfunctions.pdf Paul Halmos' NAIVE SET THEORY is the standard reference for basic set properties and now it's available cheaply!

Comment: Thanks for the information. Was what I put in the previous two posts correct?

Comment: @Will Not quite.You have to require that $a\neq 0$ and some people define $R^+$ as including 0. So it's really better to specify that $a\neq 0$. Otherwise, it looks fine, although there are other,more abstract ways to define and show it using totally ordered set properties. But since we're specifically working in the reals,this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a construction whereby every real number is really a set of things. (For the purposes of proving the equality properties, it's not material what the construction is.) We then rely on basic properties of sets.

Now, for any given sets $x$ and $y$, if we can show they have the same elements, then they are equal. Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}$. Now, treating these as sets, we know that $a$ has the same elements as itself, and thus $a = a$.

Further, if $a = b$, then $a$ and $b$ have the same elements. But then $b$ and $a$ have the same elements, and hence, $b=a$. (And vice-versa.)

You can imagine the transitive argument.

To address the inequality, simply note that if $x < y$ if and only if there exists $z \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $x + z = y$.